# Strange CLR compilation

Tags: visual-studio-2012, c++-cli, directx, clr

So I'm doing this DirectX 11 project and had to use `...array<T>^ arr` from the System header and I had to switch my Common Language RunTime Support settings to /clr. After fiddling with the other setting to get the project to compile I seem to have messed something up ,because now I cant use breakpoints and all the objects I have seem to not exist I dont know how else to put it. Please help.

Comment: Fixed the tags for you C++/CLI is not C++

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to work with .NET types, I'd recommend not using /CLR.  Instead of using `array<T>^`, you can just use `std::vector<T>` and eliminate the dependency on the common language runtime.

Comment: I forgot to say that I need to have a function with a variable number of params. Will vector<T> do the job ?

Comment: @user1523627 You can pass a variable number of elements - vector<T> grows.  Not sure what you were trying to do before...

Comment: I dont need a variable number of elements in vector<T>, I need the number of params for the function to be variable. Example : foo(a,b); and the I want to call foo(a,b,c,d) and foo is the same function.

Comment: @user1523627 That's normally handled in C++ via variadic functions: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic